# Cannot open a form in VB.net 2010 with .show()

Tags: vb.net

I am simply trying to open a new form using 'Exercise.show()' as this has work until now, however with this Exercise form, it is not being shown as an option as a form so I cannot open it.
What should I do here?

```
Private Sub Exercises_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Exercises.Click
    Exercises.Show()

    Me.Hide()

End Sub
```

Comment: It looks like an item (a button) on the current form shares the same name as the Exercises form. This is probably why you are unable to access the singleton instance of the Exercises form.

Comment: Tim Greaves is right, this code is being interpreted by the compiler as a desire for you to 'show' the button with name 'Exercises'. If you change the button name so it is something like btnExercise this will work

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Dim oForm As Exercises
oForm = New Exercises()
oForm.Show()
```

Answer (score 1):

If your actual form is called 'Exercises' then you need to type:

> ```
>     Dim frm As New Exercises        
>     frm.ShowDialog()
> ```

Thanks

Eddy Jawed

Answer (score 0):

Change .Show with ShowDialog()

```
Exercises.ShowDialog()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    Dim objPDetails As PFErrors

    Dim IsOpen As Boolean = False
    For Each f As Form In Application.OpenForms
        If f.Name = "PFErrors" Then
            IsOpen = True
            f.Focus()
            Exit For
        End If
    Next

    If IsOpen = False Then
        objPDetails = New PFErrors
        objPDetails.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized
        objPDetails.MdiParent = Me
        objPDetails.Show()
    End If
```