# How can I Restart only 1 form (Not all application) Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net

I have 2 forms(form1 , form2). The app start from form1. And the button1 closes the form1 , and open the form2.
In form2 I have a button to restart.İt should restart only form2. Not to hole app.
Basically it will does what button1 does.

I tried this one but it gives a error.

```
Me.Close()
Form1.Show()
```

error: form1 cannot reffer to itself. Use me instead. I used the Me instead.

```
Me.Close()
Me.Show()
```

After it close form. it doesn't recognize Me anymore.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cannot open a form in VB.net 2010 with .show()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15681056/cannot-open-a-form-in-vb-net-2010-with-show) and [VB.NET form.show() error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19007163/vb-net-form-show-error)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create a new instance of `Form1` (your text says `Form2` but your code says `Form1`—I go with the latter) and then show this. Finally, you can close the original.

```
Dim newForm As Form1 = New Form1()
newForm.Show()
Me.Close()
```

Comment: np - you should consider flagging this as an answer please